# Can I compartmentalize dependencies of a crate within a local dynamic rlib?

Tags: rust

I am writing a program that embeds Deno however Deno has a lot of dependencies that are using static versions which conflict with the dependencies I have in my main project.

To get around this I'm wondering if it's possible to compartmentalize my Deno integration into a seperate crate in my workspace that builds a dynamic rust library that statically contains all of its own dependencies.

I'd then consume the dynamic library dynamically from my main application.

I know that Rust doesn't have a stable ABI but, from what I understand, a library compiled on the same version of Rust as the a consumer is compatible. Given the library crate containing Deno will live/be compiled within the same workspace and built as a prerequisite to the main binary - I assume that's fine.

Is this possible and would this resolve my issues?

Is `crate-type` `rlib` the correct way to do this or would it be `lib`?

Comment: Did you already read through this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have been attempting to use the libloading crate to achieve this. The only issue is that the projects cannot be in the same Cargo workspace otherwise Cargo will still attempt to combine the dependencies. This results in Rust analyzer ignoring the dynamic library outside of the workspace, which results in a less-than ideal development experience.

Comment: Isn't this due to the fact that Rust creates monolithic blobs of code that are all linked together at compile time?  It seems that you are trying to get around this.  If you could get around it easily, then that would solve rusts slow compile times, right?